# How to remove “Null” key from HashMap<String, String>?

Tags: java, hashmap

According to Java, HashMap allowed `Null` as key. My client said

> Use `HashMap` only, Not other like HashTable,ConcurrentHashMap etc. write logic such a way that HashMap don't
>   contains `Null` as Key in my overall product logic.

I have a options like

1. Create wrapper class of HashMap and use it everywhere.

   ```
   import java.util.HashMap;

   public class WHashMap<T, K> extends HashMap<T, K> {
       @Override
       public K put(T key, K value) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if (key != null) {
               return super.put(key, value);
           }
           return null;
       }

   }
   ```
2. I suggested another option like remove null key manually or don't allowed it in each. It is also not allowed as its same operations repeated.
3. let me know..if I missed any other better approach?
4. Use HashMap with `Null`only as per java standard.

Let me know what is good approach to handle such case?

Comment: how about `Map<String, String> s = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();` it will not allow null keys

Comment: @Jobin HashMap only. Not `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: okay then what you did is correct just throw a `NPE `when key is `null`

Comment: why is it downvoted? I don't understand!!

Comment: @Jobin throw `NPE` in wrapper itself. right?

Comment: why dont ignore this constraint, and remove null by `map.remove(null)` at end?

Comment: It’s an aside: delete the line `TODO Auto-generated method stub` (it’s no longer true).

Comment: You can assert by `key.equals(new Object())` before using `put(key,value)` to force it throwing a `NullPointerException`, and weather you want to handle that or not, is up for the logic that use your `WHashMap`.

Comment: Just use HashMap (don't subclass it), and write unit tests that assert that your HashMap doesn't contain a null key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your put method implementation as follows

```
        @Override
        public K put(T key, K value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (key == null) {
              throw new NullPointerException("Key must not be null.");
            }
            return super.put(key, value);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..!!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a reasonable way to create a HashMap that *can't* contain a null key (though it's not perfect: what happens if someone calls `putAll` and passes in a map with a null key?); but I don't think that's what your client is asking for. Rather, I think your client is just saying that (s)he wants you to create a HashMap that *doesn't* contain a null key (even though it *can*). As in, (s)he just wants you to make sure that nothing in your program logic will ever put a null key in the map.

Comment: yes, you are right. we need to override all `put*` method in the wrapper class. it seems extra management. so...how can we control this?

Comment: You don't need to override `putAll` because the documentation confirms that it calls `put` (which you've already overridden). However, I agree with ruakh that you don't need to create your own subclass of HashMap. Just use HashMap, and just don't put null keys in it. It is unusual for a client to require that you use HashMap and not something equivalent - so maybe he's concerned about the performance penalties associated with things such as ConcurrentHashMap? If so, then you are also introducing a (very slight) performance penalty by checking for null every time you call your overridden `put`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: Wait, what documentation are you looking at? I checked the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll(java.util.Map) before posting my answer, and found that it did *not* confirm that.

Comment: @ruakh good point. I was incorrectly looking at the description of its superclass, AbstractMap. But HashMap.putAll is an overridden method that doesn't require `put` to be called (unlike AbstractMap). Oracle's implementation in Java 7 does in fact call `put`, but in Java 8 it doesn't.